# "message": "Call to undefined method Closure::getRelationExistenceQuery()", laravel

Tags: laravel, api, eloquent, laravel-8

I have created a function to get data from db but the function returns an error when i test with postman.

```
public function payments(){
       $data = Investigations::whereHas(function($query){
        $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%consultation%' );
       })->get();
    
        return $data;
}
```

The table has these columns

```
protected $fillable = [
        "visit", "admission_id", "type", "procedure", "quantity", "price", "discount",
        "amount", "user", "instructions", "ordered", "invoiced", "reasons", "assigned_to",
        "performing_doctor", "on_credit", "comments", "credit_status", "is_walkin",
        'service_sale_id', "cancelled", 'cancel_text', "date_changed_by", "date_adjusted_from",
        "assigned_by", "assigned_on",
        'moved_from_chargesheet', 'package_id',
        "created_at",
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see there is a "name" column.

'whereHas' used to query in a relation

```
Investigations::whereHas('relation_name', function($query){
    $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%consultation%' );
   })->get();
```

If you want to search in the current table, you can use 'where'.

it can be a condition or a function

```
Investigations::where('name', 'LIKE', '%consultation%' )->get()


                  

Investigations::where(function($query){
    $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%consultation%' );
   })->get()
```